# AngularJS, nodeJS, ReferenceError: require is not defined

Tags: node.js, json, angularjs, require, fs

I have read several similar questions here on SO but couldn't find any answer that fits my case.
I am new to angularjs and nodejs, and I am stuck here:
I would like to store the input of a form into a json file. For that I found out about this procedure:

```
        var fs = require('fs');
        fs.appendFile('../database/lexicon.json', ' This is my text.', function (err) {
        if (err) throw err;
        console.log('Updated!');
        });
```

I am just testing here with 'This is my text', and my json file is located here `../database/lexicon.json`

But the issue comes from the fact that my program doesn't recognise the `require`.
I understand that it is a server side action and that it can not run in the browser, but I thought I would overcome that issue by running my app in a local server with this command:

```
npx http-server -o
```

Can anyone help me out with this issue? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I solved the problem, not with this example, but I moved on to another feature of my app that require another `require` and I don't get the error message anymore after installing `express.js` !

I hope this will help others.